# Get Images from media library in sequence

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am building app for windows phone 7 ,where i am taking screenshot in every 1 sec and all screenshot's are saving in media library and files name are 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg.........etc. now when i am taking images from  library i am getting images randomly like (1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,7.jpg,13.jpg,4.jpg,15.jpg,5.jpg) not in sequence.
how can i get all images in sequence.here is my code

using (MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary())

{

```
PictureCollection AllScreenShot = mediaLibrary.Pictures;
foreach (Picture picture in AllScreenShot)
 {
       using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
           if (!storage.DirectoryExists("SavedImg"))
                        storage.CreateDirectory("SavedImg");

                    if (storage.FileExists("SavedImg" + "\\" + picture.Name))
                        storage.DeleteFile("SavedImg" + "\\" + picture.Name);
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = storage.CreateFile("SavedImg" + "\\" + picture.Name))
                        picture.GetImage().CopyTo(file);
        }
 }
```

}

Comment: You should get a list of all file names and sort them before reading.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of Images and store all images in a list. It would be like this,

```
List<Image> listImage = new List<Image>(10); // say 10

listImage.Add(your image Item) in your case its pic 1.jpg; // cast before adding 

List<Image> orderedList = listImage.OrderBy(k => k.ToString()).ToList();
```

Actually its not .ToString(). I declared to make you clear with the concept. In case of Image, you first need to convert it to byte[] and then store the byte[] in list and finally perform OrderBy option which will Order the images in sequence.